# Zipping for loop in fish shell (loop over multiple lists)

Tags: shell, loops, fish

I often write ad-hoc loops straight into the command-line to run a bunch of experiments. It's always a one-time thing, so writing a script file for it is unwanted overhead.

Often, though, I'd like to zip over a bunch of parameters, I would like to run a command somewhat like the following:

```
for arg1,arg2 in 256,lol 128,foo 32,bar
    ./bla --many-flags --name $arg2 --something $arg1
end
```

I can achieve something similar but quite brittle in fish with `string` (or `tr delim \n` in old versions) like so:

```
for exp in 256,lol 128,foo 32,bar
    ./bla --many-flags --name (string split ',' $exp)[2] --flag (string split ',' $exp)[1]
end
```

I'm wondering of anyone knows of better ways which don't require the cumbersome sub-command for each use of an argument (an argument may even be used multiple times), and even worse, the arbitrary delimiter which can cause all sorts of problems?

Ideally, I could even use it as a `let` like so:

```
for arg1,arg2 in 256,lol
    ./bla --many-flags --ame $arg2 --something $arg1
end
```

Comment: What is the actual input to this problem? Is it a list of comma-separated pairs? Could it be 2 lists, {256,128,32) and {lol,foo,bar} where you iterate over the indices of the lists?

Comment: One technique to assign fields of a comma-separated pair is `string split , $exp | begin; read arg1; read arg2; end` -- with this you now have values in variables for reuse.

Comment: @glennjackman that approach but `string split ',' $exp | read var1 var2`, no `begin` necessary. I think this is the best one can do.

Comment: It is for interactive use, to loop over experiment configurations, which in the most general case is a list of tuples, where the tuples can be represented however I choose to represent them, i.e. I don't care how.

The `read ...` block is a pretty nice idea and goes a long way towards what I hope for. @ridiculous_fish: I cannot get your shorter example to work, `var2` is always empty. It does work with @glenn-jackman's begin/end block syntax though.

I'm fine with accepting this as an answer, especially with @ridiculous_fish saying that's the best one can do :)

Comment: It seems that `read` now has the `-d DELIM` option, so the following is slightly shorter: `echo $exp | read -d , var1 var2` and actually works, as opposed to ridiculous_fish's which always left var2 empty when I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments on the question, this is not supported. The closest workaround seems to be:

```sh
for exp in 256,lol 128,foo 32,bar
    echo $exp | read -d , arg1 arg2
    ./bla --many-flags --name $arg2 --flag $arg1
end
```

Not quite satisfying for regular interactive use, but I'll survive it I guess.

Comment: A combination of `paste`, `seq`, and `psub` can achieve e.g. numbered entries: `for tuple in (paste -d ',' (seq 1 5 | psub) list-of-files.txt); echo $tuple | read -d ',' i file; echo $i $file; end`.

Comment: Note how I mention that I'm asking for interactive use, so your comment does not address my use-case at all. Although maybe it can help someone else I guess.

Comment: "maybe it can help some else I guess" -> That's the idea ;) I needed the fish-equivalent of `zip` myself and found this question, so plugged in the solution to my own `zip` issue which I'm guessing/hoping others will find helpful.